# How to show that quantum $sl_2 (\mathbb C)$ is a Hopf algebra deformation of $U (sl_2 (\mathbb C))\ $?

Tags: lie-algebras, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

The quantum $sl_2 (\mathbb C)$ is the non-commutative, non-cocommutative Hopf algebra $U_h (sl_2 (\mathbb C))$ over the ring $\mathbb C [[h]]$ generated by $E, F$ and $H$ with the relations $:$

$$[H, E] = 2 E,\ \  [H, F] = - 2 F, \ \  [E,F] = \frac {e^{hH} - e^{-hH}} {e^h - e^{-h}}.$$

The comultiplication $\Delta_h,$ the counit $\varepsilon_h$ and the antipode $S_h$ on $U_h (sl_2 (\mathbb C))$ are defined as follows $:$

$$\Delta_h (E) = E \otimes e^{hH} + 1 \otimes E  , \ \ \Delta_h (F) = F \otimes 1 + e^{-hH} \otimes F ,\\ \Delta_h (H) = 1 \otimes H + H \otimes 1,$$

$$\varepsilon_h (E) = \varepsilon_h (F) = \varepsilon_h (H) = 0,$$

$$S_h (E) = - Ee^{-hH}, \ \ S_h (F) = - e^{hH} F, \ \ S_h(H) = - H.$$

It can be easily shown to be a Hopf algebra over the ring $\mathbb C [[h]].$ It is also easy to show that $\Delta_h \equiv \Delta\ (\text {mod}\ h)$ and $\mu_h \equiv \mu\ (\text {mod}\ h),$ where $\Delta$ and $\mu$ are respectively the comultiplication and the multiplication defined on the cocommutative Hopf algebra $U (sl_2 (\mathbb C))$ over $\mathbb C.$ So in order to show that $U_h (sl_2 (\mathbb C))$ is a Hopf algebra deformation of $U (sl_2 (\mathbb C))$ (according to the definition given in the book *A Guide to Quantum Groups* by Chari and Pressley) the only thing we need to show is that $U_h (sl_2 (\mathbb C)) \simeq U(sl_2 (\mathbb C)) [[h]]$ as a $\mathbb C [[h]]$-modulè.

This is the part where I got stuck. Could anyone give me some suggestion in this regard? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I cannot be of great help but I have the impression that all you need is a proof that $U_h(sl_2(\mathbb{C}))$ has a Poincaré-Birkhoff-Wit basis. If so, then $U_h(sl_2(\mathbb{C}))$ is a free $\mathbb{C}[[h]]$-module showing that $U_h(sl_2(\mathbb{C})) \simeq U(sl_2(\mathbb{C})) \otimes \mathbb{C}[[h]]$. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed, probably the easiest way to do this in general is to construct a PBW basis. Note that, again for arbitrary simple Lie algebra $g$, $U_h(g)$ is in fact isomorphic to $U(g)[[h]]$ as an algebra and not just as a $C[[h]]$-module. For $g=\mathfrak{sl}_2$ this algebra isomorphism can be constructed explicitly, see Prop 6.4.6 In Chari Presley or Appel--Gautham https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03601.